# Is "master" a standard branch name in git, or is it just the standard practice?

Tags: git, version-control

I noticed the names "master" and "origin" being used a lot in git.  What's the difference between these, and are either standard in git, or are they just common practice?  Which would be the root folder of the repository?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`master` is the default branch that is created in Git when you create a repo. It is pretty standard, but you may have a repo without master branch. You can delete or rename it, but it is generally not advised.

`origin` is the remote from which you clone from and is set up by git. It is also pretty standard, but you may delete it or rename it or add a remote origin without cloning.

Note that all repos created in git come with master. But only cloned ones come with origin.